# I want to pass a unique variable ie product code or product id from database in url of a product

Tags: php

I want to pass a unique variable i.e. product code or product id from database in url of a product and every product will have its own link dynamically in php

Comment: Some things to READ : [FAQs](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) -- [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) -- [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/docs.php)

Comment: well for that reQuestIon I want to get money..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Get Variables

like:

```
sitename.com/index.php?id=1234
```

And in the index.php something like:

```
<?php
    $DBuser = "XXX";
    $DBpassword = "XXX";
    $DBhost = "localhost"; 
    $DBname = "XXX";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpassword, $DBname);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    if ($result=$mysqli->multi_query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."' LIMIT 1")) {
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
        print_r($data);
    } else
        echo "Error, id not found";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.. I know this is a stupid question but i had just begin to learn php.

Comment: No problem, just let me know if that worked for you ;)